# Sql report builder, stuck

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I made a report in report builder,
it works but I should add another division , the 'name' field brings 4 types of materials in square meters, and I would like to make the transition from square meters to whole plates, and each material has a different value to which it is divided, do you have any idea how I could end it

example :
if it is 'bla', the result should be divided by 4.1, if it is 'pal' the result should be divided by 5.91 .. etc

[image: Report Tabel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something like

```
=Fields!myAreaField.Value 
 / 
 (SWITCH
     LEFT(Fields!Name.Value, 3) = "BLA", 4.1,         
     LEFT(Fields!Name.Value, 3) = "PAL", 5.91,
     LEFT(Fields!Name.Value, 3) = "HDF", 1.23,
     True, 1
)
```

This will take the number from `myAreaField` and divide it based on the first 3 characters in the `Name` field. Just add more expressions as required. The final `True, 1` just means that if there is no match in the previous expressions the result will remain the same as `myAreaField`

Comment: Thanks for answer, i will try :D:D !!

Comment: No problem. Remember that if this does answer your question, please mark the answer as accepted (the check box below the vote up/down buttons to the left). This helps other SO users find answers in the furture.